# Adding support for SwiftPM to Swift Library

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

Last one hour or so I have been looking at how to add SwiftPM support to the open-source library. 
I started mimicking Alamofire's Package.swift file.

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(name: "MASegmentedControl",
                      platforms: [.iOS(.v10)],
                      products: [.library(name: "MASegmentedControl",
                                          targets: ["MASegmentedControl"])],
                      targets: [.target(name: "MASegmentedControl",
                                        path: "MASegmentedControl")],
                      swiftLanguageVersions: [.v4, .v4_2, .v5])
```

But when I am trying to add that to a test project as swift package I am getting error as shown below.

[image: screenshot]

When I run `swift package tools-version` I get the output as `3.1.0`. I am running Xcode 11.2.1. 
I also tried looking at `how to update swift package tool`. I couldn't find anything on it. 
I am wondering if anyone of you added SwiftPM support to your libraries, can please help me out. I am missing something but I can't put my finger on it. 
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be appeared due to one of the following:

1- Regarding the documentation, May you need to remove the "swiftLanguageVersions" key.

https://swift.org/blog/swift-package-manager-manifest-api-redesign/

> The tools version also determines the default Swift language version
>   used to compile the package’s sources. Existing Swift 3 packages will
>   compile in Swift 3 compatibility mode. You can optionally use the
>   swiftLanguageVersions property in both Swift 3 and Swift 4 manifests
>   to set the language version used to compile that package, if you don’t
>   want the default version. This means it is possible to upgrade a
>   package to use the newer manifest format without upgrading its sources
>   to Swift 4.

2- Ensure the following format for the commented line, as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1

import PackageDescription
```

> // swift-tools-version:. Packages that omit this special
>   comment will default to tools version 3.1.0.